# Android VideoView playing stream on emulator, not on real device?

Tags: android, video, stream

i'm trying to play a stream coming from my raspberry pi on my android phone. 
i found code to play this stream in a videoview like this:

```
private void playStream(String src){
 Uri UriSrc = Uri.parse(src);
    if(UriSrc == null){
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
      "UriSrc == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
     streamView.setVideoURI(UriSrc);
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        streamView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        streamView.start();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
         "Connect: " + src, 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

where src is a plain string with the ip/port.

when i run this in the emulator with src pointing to my local raspberry pi @ port 8090 it starts to display the stream as expected.

i even found out that i could just start the native android player with the ip/port string and that it would open up in fullscreen mode playing back the stream.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://192.168.2.189:8090"), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

however when i create an apk and install and run this on my android 6 device (A5 2016), the first version will just tell me "sorry, this video cannot be played back", while the second version will load infinitely without ever displaying something.

can someone pls help? i really don't want to use a third party app like vlc player to view the stream but have it displayed in my own app or the android native video player.

note: the stream runs perfectly fine in the vlc app on my phone.

additional info:

this is the command used on the pi to create the stream:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 | cvlc stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090}' :demux=h264
```

Comment: if you down-vote my question, please leave at least a comment why you did it, so i can improve it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### my solution:

use another stream format.

i now use HLS, which requires you to setup a http server like nginx on your raspberry pi.

note that HLS will work on android and iphone, but not on windows pc browsers (except microsoft edge).

### my conclusion:

the format used before was not, or at least not anymore, compatible with android. yet it somehow worked in the emulator..

### final code used in the android app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://192.168.2.189/hls/stream.m3u8"),"video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

### raspberry pi steps to create the stream data:

create a new folder within your site path. this is not necessary but for keeping stream segments seperated from other webcontent.

next create a script like this to start your stream:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

base="/var/www/pisite/hls/"

raspivid -n -ih -t 0 -w 1280 -h 720 -fps 25 -o - | sudo ffmpeg -y \
-i - \
-c:v copy \
-map 0 \
-f ssegment \
-segment_time 1 \
-segment_format mpegts \
-segment_list "$base/stream.m3u8" \
-segment_list_size 10 \
-segment_wrap 20 \
-segment_list_flags +live \
-segment_list_type m3u8 \
"$base/%03d.ts"
```

this will create the stream.m3u8 file accessed by the android app. 
it will only ever use 10 segment files, so it can run indefinitely.

note that your pi needs some startup time before you connect through the app to the stream or it will fail.